# Starting PHP Calendar from Monday w/ Correct ColSpan

Tags: php, calendar

Im trying to amend an online PHP calendar code to start on Monday not Sunday.

I need for the calendar when i return this in PHP to be in the following array:

Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri.

It starts on Sunday and works fine but I would like to tweak this.

I have tried myself but this is a little advices beyond my skills. Any help is much appreciated.

```
function build_calendar($month,$year,$hide) 
{

    // Create array containing abbreviations of days of week.
    $daysOfWeek = array('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun');

    // What is the first day of the month in question?
    $firstDayOfMonth = mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year);

    // How many days does this month contain?
    $numberDays = date('t',$firstDayOfMonth);

    // Retrieve some information about the first day of the
    // month in question.
    $dateComponents = getdate($firstDayOfMonth);

    // What is the name of the month in question?
    $monthName = $dateComponents['month'];

    // What is the index value (0-6) of the first day of the
    // month in question.
    $dayOfWeek = $dateComponents['wday'];

    // Create the table tag opener and day headers

    $calendar = '';

    if ($hide == true) {
        $calendar .= "<div class='date_picker' style='display:none;' data-month='".$month."'>";
        $calendar .= "<div class='date_picker__wrap'>";
        $calendar .= "<a class='date_picker--prev'>Previous</a>";
        $calendar .= "<h2>$monthName, $year</h2>";
        $calendar .= "<a class='date_picker--next'>Next</a>";
        $calendar .= "</div>";
        $calendar .= "<table class='table table-bordered table-hover date_picker__calendar'>";
    } else {
        $calendar .= "<div class='date_picker date_picker__current' data-month='".$month."'>";
        $calendar .= "<div class='date_picker__wrap'>";
        $calendar .= "<a class='date_picker--prev'>Previous</a>";
        $calendar .= "<h2>$monthName, $year</h2>";
        $calendar .= "<a class='date_picker--next'>Next</a>";
        $calendar .= "</div>";
        $calendar .= "<table class='table table-bordered table-hover date_picker__calendar'>";
    }

    $calendar .= "<tr>";

    // Create the calendar headers

    foreach($daysOfWeek as $day) {
         $calendar .= "<th class='header'>$day</th>";
    } 

    // Create the rest of the calendar

    // Initiate the day counter, starting with the 1st.
    $currentDay = 1;

    $calendar .= "</tr><tr>";

    // The variable $dayOfWeek is used to
    // ensure that the calendar
    // display consists of exactly 7 columns.

    if ($dayOfWeek > 0) { 
         $calendar .= "<td style='background: #f9f9f9;' colspan='$dayOfWeek'>&nbsp;</td>"; 
    }

    $month = str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

    while ($currentDay <= $numberDays) {

      // Seventh column (Saturday) reached. Start a new row.

      if ($dayOfWeek == 7) {

           $dayOfWeek = 0;
           $calendar .= "</tr><tr>";

      }

      $currentDayRel = str_pad($currentDay, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

      $date = "$year-$month-$currentDayRel";

      if (date('d') == $currentDay && date('n') == $month) {
           $add_class = ' today';
      } else {
           $add_class = '';
      }

      if (date('d') > $currentDay && date('n') == $month) {
           $add_class .= ' disable';
      }

      if ($dayOfWeek == 6 || $dayOfWeek == 0) {
           $calendar .= "<td class='day weekend".$add_class."' data-date='$date'><span class='actual_day'>$currentDay</span><span class='price'>+£50</span></td>";
      } else {
           $calendar .= "<td class='day weekday".$add_class."' data-date='$date'><span class='actual_day'>$currentDay</span><span class='price'>-£50</span></td>";
      };

      // Increment counters

      $currentDay++;
      $dayOfWeek++;

    }

    // Complete the row of the last week in month, if necessary

    if ($dayOfWeek != 7) { 

         $remainingDays = 7 - $dayOfWeek;
         $calendar .= "<td style='background: #f9f9f9;' colspan='$remainingDays'>&nbsp;</td>"; 

    }

    $calendar .= "</tr>";
    $calendar .= "</table>";
    $calendar .= "</div>";

    return $calendar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive managed to solve this myself:

```
    function build_calendar($month,$year,$hide) 
{

    // Create array containing abbreviations of days of week.
    $daysOfWeek = array('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun');

    // What is the first day of the month in question?
    $firstDayOfMonth = mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year);

    // How many days does this month contain?
    $numberDays = date('t',$firstDayOfMonth);

    // Retrieve some information about the first day of the
    // month in question.
    $dateComponents = getdate($firstDayOfMonth);

    // What is the name of the month in question?
    $monthName = $dateComponents['month'];

    // What is the index value (0-6) of the first day of the
    // month in question.
    $dayOfWeek = $dateComponents['wday'] - 1;

    // Create the table tag opener and day headers
    $calendar = '';

    if ($hide == true) {
        $calendar .= "<div class='date_picker' style='display:none;' data-month='".$month."'>";
        $calendar .= "<div class='date_picker__wrap'>";
        $calendar .= "<a class='date_picker--prev'>Previous</a>";
        $calendar .= "<h2>$monthName, $year</h2>";
        $calendar .= "<a class='date_picker--next'>Next</a>";
        $calendar .= "</div>";
        $calendar .= "<table class='table table-bordered table-hover date_picker__calendar'>";
    } else {
        $calendar .= "<div class='date_picker date_picker__current' data-month='".$month."'>";
        $calendar .= "<div class='date_picker__wrap'>";
        $calendar .= "<a class='date_picker--prev'>Previous</a>";
        $calendar .= "<h2>$monthName, $year</h2>";
        $calendar .= "<a class='date_picker--next'>Next</a>";
        $calendar .= "</div>";
        $calendar .= "<table class='table table-bordered table-hover date_picker__calendar'>";
    }

    $calendar .= "<tr>";

    // Create the calendar headers

    foreach($daysOfWeek as $day) {
         $calendar .= "<th class='header'>$day</th>";
    } 

    // Create the rest of the calendar

    // Initiate the day counter, starting with the 1st.
    $currentDay = 1;

    $calendar .= "</tr><tr>";

    // The variable $dayOfWeek is used to
    // ensure that the calendar
    // display consists of exactly 7 columns.

    if ($dayOfWeek > 0) {
         $calendar .= "<td style='background: #f9f9f9;' colspan='$dayOfWeek'>&nbsp;</td>"; 
    }

    if ($dayOfWeek == -1) {
      $calendar .= "<td style='background: #f9f9f9;' colspan='6'>&nbsp;</td>"; 
    }

    $month = str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

    while ($currentDay <= $numberDays) {

      // Seventh column (Saturday) reached. Start a new row.

      if ($dayOfWeek == 7 || $dayOfWeek == 0) {

           $dayOfWeek = 0;
           $calendar .= "</tr><tr>";

      }

      $currentDayRel = str_pad($currentDay, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

      $date = "$year-$month-$currentDayRel";

      if (date('d') == $currentDay && date('n') == $month) {
           $add_class = ' today';
      } else {
           $add_class = '';
      }

      if (date('d') > $currentDay && date('n') == $month) {
           $add_class .= ' disable';
      }

      if ($dayOfWeek == 5 || $dayOfWeek == 6) {
           $calendar .= "<td class='day weekend".$add_class."' data-date='$date' data-week='$dayOfWeek'><span class='actual_day'>$currentDay</span><span class='price'>+£50</span></td>";
      } else {
           $calendar .= "<td class='day weekday".$add_class."' data-date='$date' data-week='$dayOfWeek'><span class='actual_day'>$currentDay</span><span class='price'>-£50</span></td>";
      };

      // Increment counters

      $currentDay++;
      $dayOfWeek++;

    }

    // Complete the row of the last week in month, if necessary

    if ($dayOfWeek != 7) { 

         $remainingDays = 7 - $dayOfWeek;
         $calendar .= "<td style='background: #f9f9f9;' colspan='$remainingDays'>&nbsp;</td>"; 

    }

    $calendar .= "</tr>";
    $calendar .= "</table>";
    $calendar .= "</div>";

    return $calendar;
```

}